# YUI Calendar highlight current daty

Tags: javascript, calendar, yui

I use YUI 3 Calendar to display javascript calendar on my webpage. How to add class that would highlight current day on YUI 3 Calendar?

Answer (score 0):

Use yourCalendarObject.selectDates(), for documentation look here - http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Calendar.html#method_selectDates